# Clone filter gallery jQuery plugin in a single page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to clone/duplicate this (demo URL is given below) filter gallery jQuery plugin multiple times in a single page? Any help would be appreciated

Demo :

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your error is a syntax error, you forgot to close `$(document).ready` function, close it (**i.e. `});`**) and your issue will be solved.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".filter-button2").click(function() {
          var value = $(this).attr('data-filter2');

          if (value == "all") {
              $('.filter2').show('1000');
          } else {
              $(".filter2").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
              $('.filter2').filter('.' + value).show('3000');
          }
          $(".filter-button2").removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass("active");
      });
  });
```